# Has anyone read/debunked Yessenin-Volpin–Hennix “Beware of the Gödel-Wette paradox”?

Tags: lo.logic, paradox

A student recently asked me about the status of a 2001 arXiv post, [Beware of the Gödel-Wette paradox!](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110094), by Alexander Yessenin-Volpin (aka Esenin-Volpin and several other transliterations) and Catherine Christer Hennix.

It claims to give a counter-example to Gödel’s second incompleteness theorem, which of course sets off the crackpot alarm.  However, at least Yesenin-Volpin has done enough other serious and thought-provoking work (albeit more philosophy-of-maths than straight-up mathematics) that I am uncomfortable dismissing the paper without some consideration.  I presume it either has an error, or works in a non-standard meta-mathematical setting, or in some other way does something weaker than it seems to claim; but it would be nice to substantiate this suspicion and find out which of these is the case.

Has anyone read this paper carefully, and discussed/debunked it?

Comment: Read 109 pages of known ultrafinitistic "disproving" a well-known theorem? Pass.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sure, I don’t particularly want to do it myself either, hence asking if someone already has.  But when cranks accuse mathematicians of being hidebound reactionaries ignoring their work, we say that no, there are clear standards of correctness that they fail to live up to.  And to substantiate this, we need (as a community) to give attention from time to time to some of the more coherent “outsider” papers, and show how they are in error.  (And occasionally we may find that they’re not — though, again, I highly doubt that in this case.)

Comment: The problem, and it applies more or less to that 300 pages long paper about why inaccessible cardinals are inconsistent, is that when a mathematician has to take several months of their time to read, analyze and understand something of this caliber, which clearly doesn't sit right with all previously known and thoroughly checked mathematics... it's impossible to persuade anyone to read it. Not to mention that you've never heard about an ultrafinitist going "Oh.... alright then, infinite set are consistent" after being explained their mistakes. So, again, why bother.

Comment: (Don't get me wrong, though, I do understand your argument that when presented with superficially up-to-standards work, we need to at least take it somewhat seriously. At least at first.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila It might not be so bad as that. Remember a few years ago when Nelson announced the inconsistency of PA? He was no crackpot either. I don't recall how long his official purported proof was -- it might have been comparable in length to this one -- but the error in his reasoning was sniffed out fairly quickly (by none other than Terence Tao). https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/09/the_inconsistency_of_arithmeti.html The same could happen here.

Comment: @Todd: As far as I remember, Nelson didn't even manage to finish the full write-up of his proof (which was indeed projected to be quite long). In any case, the mistake was identified in an outline he published along with the original anouncement, which only involved a handful of pages.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for your recollection. I still think the same could happen here.

Comment: @Todd: Looking at the typography of the pdf, I have to say that even if it was a mathematically interesting paper, I would have hesitated to read it thoroughly. I've seen typewriter printed books that were much easier to read than that.

Comment: All I know is that I bought an experimental music album by Catherine Christer Hennix which had liner notes full of pseudo-mathematical jargon, so, perhaps unfairly, I'm slightly disinclined to take any purported mathematics by her too seriously. The music was pretty solid though.

Comment: @Peter and Asaf: "But when cranks accuse mathematicians of being hidebound reactionaries ignoring their work, we say that no, there are clear standards of correctness that they fail to live up to."  
 
"...when a mathematician has to take several months of their time to read, analyze and understand something of this caliber, which clearly doesn't sit right with all previously known and thoroughly checked mathematics... it's impossible to persuade anyone to read it."

And yet - or perhaps for that very reason - one may still encounter demonstrably more cranky work in reputable journals.

Comment: @Adam: I do not recall, at this time, anything comparable to disproving the incompleteness theorem in any peer reviewed journal I've seen.

Comment: @Asaf Nor I, but some amazing things still.